# Dynamic Proxy CXF Web Service

Tags: redirect, web, service, proxy, cxf

I have two identical CXF 3.1 web services Service_A and Service_B that have the same WSDL files. Service_A is deployed on Server_X and Service_B is deployed on Service_Y. Is there a way to implement a CXF web service Service_C deployed on Server_Z that will play the role of a dynamic proxy web service. Service_C is supposed to have the same WSDL file as Service_A and Service_B but it will redirect the SOAP requests to Service_A or Service_B and send back the SOAP response to the client.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. You service C receives the request and calls the corresponding endpoint in either service A or service B in alternating fashion (Round Robin) and returns to the client whatever response the call to the service A or B returned.

Other than that I'd suggest using Apache or Nginx instead of Service C on Server Z to basically do this load-balancing act for you. A load balancer will do a far better job forwarding your client requests to service A or B than from your service C.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! Is there a way to code the web service C in a generic manner without the need to generate operation classes?

Comment: You would have the endpoints of A and the endpoints of B implemented in web service C. Service C gets the request and knows to call the corresponding endpoints of either Service A or Service B.

Comment: How to programmatically achieve that? I implemented a Servlet filter and I didn't work.

Comment: You still have to code operations in web service C. It will act as a service facade to two business services (in this case service A & B). To call service A & B's endpoints from inside your Service C, use RestTemplate.                    Example:                                                                                      RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);